# control may reach end of non-void function xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2012

I have a third party library code segment which has the following structure:

```
class A;

A func()
{
   if(...)
   {
       return A(...);
   }
   else if(...)
   {
       return A(...);
   }
   else
   {
       LOG(...);
   }

}
```

And it gives the error "control may reach end of non-void function" in Xcode.

The same segment does compile in VS2012 without any problem. Xcode c++ compiler dialect and standard library is set to C++89 and libstdc++. I know that this is an expected behaviour but doesn't vs2012 compiler behave in accordance with the standards?

Comment: What does the LOG() macro do?

Comment: You may have set one of the flags that make warnings into errors. But do you really want that code to compile?

Comment: You are missing a `return` in the `else` branch or before end of function scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing something like

```
Type func()
{
     ...
}
```

The compiler expect you to return an object of type `Type` **in every paths** of the function, which is not what you do here.

Or your `LOG` function return an `A` object, which I doubt, and you should write `return LOG()`, or your `LOG` is just about logging and you should return `A`, `null`, throw an exception or whatever you need, but don't reach the end of the function without returning anything.

---

I don't know why `VS2012` compile whereas, IMHO, it shouldn't but even if it does, don't write code like that, you'll get some surprises later on your project.

Answer (score 2):

In this part of the function

```
   else
   {
       LOG(...);
   }
```

it returns nothing to the caller though the function is declared as having a return type that is not void.

I do not know but eiether you should write

```
   else
   {
       return LOG(...);
   }
```

or add one more statement with return

```
   else
   {
       LOG(...);
       return some_value; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a turnaround, I have resolved the issue by returning some dummy object after LOG(...):

```
A func()
{
   if(...)
   {
       return A(...);
   }
   else if(...)
   {
       return A(...);
   }
   else
   {
       LOG(...);
       return A(...);
   }

}
```

Comment: Great, that's what I said :)